# Failed to create the global_planner/GlobalPlanner planner

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setup: ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04

on the TurtleBot platform, when launching the move_base node configured for the global_planner/GlobalPlanner, I receive the following error:

`Failed to create the global_planner/GlobalPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class global_planner/GlobalPlanner with base class type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are navfn/NavfnROS`

I load `move_base_params.yaml` within `move_base` as follows:

`<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen" >`
`<rosparam file="$(find robust_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />`

where the `base_global_planner` param is defined in `move_base_params.yaml` as follows:
`base_global_planner: "global_planner/GlobalPlanner"`

I've re-installed the nav stack and re-built my workspace to no avail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276939/failed-to-create-the-global_planner/globalplanner-planner/) by [ryanoldja](https://answers.ros.org/users/30719/ryanoldja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2017-11-30**:
What does `rospack find global_planner` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

very sorry, the problem seems to have been caused by sourcing conflicting workspace. this is resolved. thanks!

---

Originally posted by [ryanoldja](https://answers.ros.org/users/30719/ryanoldja/) with karma: 60 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-05-28**:
Hello, Could you explain how did you resolve this issue? I am also facing the same error. I have created my own local planner. Thank you.

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-13**:
@mallikarjun have you figured this out?  I am facing the same issue

**Comment by [AKN](https://answers.ros.org/users/53921/akn/) on 2020-04-23**:
Most likely, you are miising the global_planner package. Use to following command to install it, e.g. for melodic:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-global_planner